# Typescript base type off of value

Tags: typescript

I have a typescript object where the type of one attribute depends on the value of another.

The type objects I have now are as follows:`enter code here`

```
export enum GameType {
  WORDLE = "wordle",
  CROSSWORD = "crossword",
}

export type WordleKey = {
  answer: string[];
};

export type CrosswordKey = {
  grid: number[];
};

export type GenericGameKey = WordleKey | CrosswordKey;

export type GameDocument<SolutionKey extends GenericGameKey = GenericGameKey> = {
  gameType: GameType;
  solutionKey: SolutionKey;
}
```

The idea is when I get an object of this generic GameDocument type, I will be able to use the `gameType` object to typecast the generic `solutionKey`.

For example, I get an untyped object from my API whose `solutionKey` is of type `WordleKey`

```
const wordleGameDocument = {
   gameType: GameType.WORDLE
   answer: ['T', 'E']
}
```

I would use the `gameType` attribute in some type of enum -> type mapper to give me the type I want so I can then type the untyped object. An example of this is as follows:

```
export const GameTypeMap = {
  [GameType.WORDLE]: WordleKey;
  [GameType.CROSSWORD]: CrosswordKey;
};
const gameType = wordleGameDocument.gameType
const documentType = GameTypeMap[gameType]
const solutionKey = wordleGameDocument as GameDocument<documentType>
```

However I do not believe it is possible to have types as a value in a map. I realize I can do this via a switch statement on `GameType` and then use type casting but my real `GameType` enum object will be hundreds of entries long so I would prefer to avoid that if possible. ANy thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

This is a common conceptual pitfall that folks fall into with TS. In TS the types do not exist at all in the runtime as they are compiled away. That means `[GameType.WORDLE]: WordleKey;` for example is an impossible statement as you are assigning a runtime var to a TS type that doesn't even exist as a concept in the runtime.

When you cast something, that has no bearing on the runtime either.

You need to define all the types as a [discriminated union](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/discriminated-unions) and then where you need to access properties specific to a certain type, you will use if's on the discriminator which will type narrow according to the condition. The if is totally unavoidable, because you need that to actually do something in the runtime to ensure it is the right type; unless you cast, but then you are opting out of type safety by saying it is something without actually checking.

This is quite different to nominally typed languages like Java/C# etc.

```
export enum GameType {
  WORDLE = "wordle",
  CROSSWORD = "crossword",
}

export type WordleDocument = {
  gameType: GameType.WORDLE
  answer: string[];
};

export type CrosswordDocument = {
  gameType: GameType.CROSSWORD 
  grid: number[];
};


type GameDocument = WordleDocument | CrosswordDocument 

// example 
if (wordleGameDocument.gameType === GameType.WORDLE) {
   console.log(wordleGameDocument.answer) // Inside if, TS will recognise wordleGameDocument as WordleDocument since we type narrowed it via the discriminated union
}
```

By the way, for your scale challenge, usually you solve this by autogenerating types based off your API schema (openapi, graphql etc) or using something like `tRPC`.

Comment: Thank you! Very very helpful. I'll probably end up doing something like that if statement. Will look into that